# How to count and group query to get proper results?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a problem, please see my database:

```
-------------------
| id | article_id |
-------------------
| 1  |      1     |
| 2  |      1     |
| 3  |      1     |
| 4  |      2     |
| 5  |      2     |
| 6  |      3     |
| 7  |      3     |
| 8  |      3     |
| 9  |      3     |
| 10 |      3     |
```

And I want to receive something like this (order by votes, from max to min):

```
---------------------------
| id | article_id | votes |
---------------------------
| 1  |      3     |    5  |
| 2  |      1     |    3  |
| 3  |      2     |    2  |
```

Could you please help me to write proper sql query?

Comment: I want to create "votes" column by query

Comment: can you give more clarity to the question?
Do you mean ID here (on the first block) as vote for an article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT article_id, COUNT(article_id) AS votes
FROM votes_table
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SET @currentRow = 0;
SELECT @currentRow := @currentRow + 1 AS id, t.article_id, t.c AS `votes`
FROM (
    SELECT article_id, count(*) as `c`
    FROM table_votes
    GROUP BY article_id
    ) t
ORDER BY t.c DESC
```

please note that you can't select an id column like this in this context, and your "expected result" is incorrect. I tried to adapt it at a maximum.

cheers

Comment: Well you cán have a counting column, using a variable. But most of the times the reason why people think they need it, is wrong. Either it should be in the table, or generated at application level.

Comment: I was adding it while you commented :-) you're totally right reguarding to the analysis though, but from the point of view of giving an answer I included it.